# Copy file from remote server to local server not working

Tags: linux, postgresql, scp

I ssh to my server and used sudo su - postgres and become postgres and taken backup of db using pg_dump. Now how can i send that file to my local machine. I'm not able to scp as my file is in postgres user

Can some one suggest me how to get the backedup file to my local machine.

Comment: Sounds like a question for ServerFault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your server, change the ownership of the file to the user which you use to login. Then you will be able to scp it to local machine. Please refer [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/chown.1.html) for chown

Answer (score 1):

As @Thanga has mentioned you will need to chown on the file to allow usage. Also, what I have found with remote servers is that you can not scp from the server to your local machine, you will need to 'pull' the file from the server to your machine. So instead of

`scp /home/usr/file.txt @local_machine/home/Documents`

you need to

`scp @remote_server/home/usr/file.txt /home/Documents`

Hope that makes sense.